# Get a datastore object by getattr without knowing its class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, referenceproperty

I want to get a entity through a ReferencePropery in this way.

```
getattr(model, refrence)
```

where model is a `db.Model` and reference is `db.ReferenceProperty`. But I get a KindError, which I can avoid by adding import of following sort.

```
from foomodule import ReferedKind
```

Where `ReferedKind` is the class of the entity I want to get by above `getattr`.

But my problem is in my case because of the nature of the function I want to call this in, the `model` can belong to any Model class of mine. So I don't know what the `ReferedKind` will be.

How can I call `getattr` and get the referred entity without importing every possible model class?

Is there a way I can know the class of a entity referred by a `ReferanceProperty` in advance so I can dynamically import it?

**Aditional info**

I am writing a function that would return a json serializable python dict. Because in some cases dictionary returned by db.to_dict() is not json serializable. So the function doesn't know in advance what kind of a model it will have to put into a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you need to import all potential models that you could retrieve before doing anything.

Your making things hard for yourself.

The only way you do it would be to work at a lower level than db.Model or ndb.Model to fetch the raw data  then examine it then you will still need to import the model before dereferencing a referenceproperty or fetching a key.

If you decide to do this ndm will be easier as it doesn't have a reference property, but a KeyProperty, you can use getattr, check if you have a key, then fetch the object referred to be the key.

If you want to stick with db.  it will be messy because you need to use `get_value_for_datastore`

Which would involve,

getting the class of the entity, getting the property of the class and then calling get_value_for_datastore passing in the instance then assuming you have imported the you can get the key.

so if you have an instance from the datastore called foo you would

```
prop = getattr(foo.__class__,"the_property_name")
obj_key = prop.get_value_for_datastore(foo)
```

Then you will need to get the kind from the key, then work out how to import the model for that kind, before you get() the key, other wise you will still get the `KindError`

I am not sure all the effort is worth it,  you will find it easier to just import the models.  You ultimately need to import any model before you use it. The only thing you are might be gaining is a lazy import potentially saving some startup time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. From your answer I realized that this thing is easier with ndb models. But I already have existing db models and transition to ndb will take some time. So i guess I am stuck with importing everything. I can now see that other workarounds are tiresome. Thanks for your time.